# What does this mean? "If an angle is inscribed into each of the four segments outside the quadrilateral [that is inscribed in a circle] ..."

Tags: geometry

I don't know if this should be on English Language Learners or this site, but what does this mean?

> A quadrilateral is inscribed in a circle. **If an angle is inscribed into each of the four segments outside the quadrilateral**, the sum of these four angles, expressed in degrees, is: ..."

I've highlighted in bold what I don't understand.

Comment: I don't blame you for being confused.  I don't think the question is using proper english and I don't think that description makes any sense.  However what I think the mean is this:  Suppose one of the segments is $\overline{AB}$.  That is to say; $A$ is a point of a circle, $B$ is a point of the circle and $\overline{AB}$ is the line segment connecting them.  Now let $K$ be a point of the circle so that $K$ is between $A$ and $B$ on the circle.  Consider the angle $\angle AKB$.  I believe the question is describing that sort of angle.

Comment: I concur with @fleablood. Note that the part of the circle on one side of a chord is commonly called a "segment" (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) into which they are apparently "inscribing an angle".

Comment: By taking the meaning that @fleablood suggests, I am getting the answer as $540^{\circ}$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angles they are considering are those highlighted in green. Their sum is $540°$, by the way.

They had to specify like this:

"If an angle is inscribed into each of the four *circular* segments outside the quadrilateral[...]"

---

[image]